# How to customize the Appointment Form when creating or editing one of the records?

Tags: devexpress

I'm wondering how I can add new checkboxes or remove the existing checkboxes like "All Day"? Also, how can I apply custom CSS and change the predefined buttons in the component? Is there anyway I can change custom styles ?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or the HTML5/JS DevExtreme Library?